# Sqlite3's create_function() method for specific searching

Tags: python, database, sqlite, anki

Hi I'm currently working on a python/anki project in order to turn my language learning journey into a more automate process. I was at the moment searching for a way to use "sqlite3" library in order to define a function that could retrieve from the database only rows which contain a word the japanese dictionary form so it could match also conjugated words in my database sentences. Here is my example :

```
import sqlite3
from sudachipy import dictionary, Tokenizer
import sudachipy
conn = sqlite3.connect("D:/ajatt/copyankidb/collection.anki2")  #my ankidatabase
                                                                #to retrieve specific sentences
c = conn.cursor()
tokenizer = dictionary.Dictionary().create(mode= sudachipy.SplitMode.C)
yahoosent = "走る" #the key word 

def samewordsearcher(data):
    for outword in tokenizer.tokenize(yahoosent): #tokenize create a token object so i can apply additional methods
        for inword in tokenizer.tokenize(data):   #like dictionary_form() which gives the dictionary form of a
                                                  #japanese word
            if outword.dictionary_form() == inword.dictionary_form(): 
                return data
            else:
                return None


conn.create_function("SAMEWORD",1,samewordsearcher)
sqlsent = f"SELECT SAMEWORD(sfld) FROM Notes"
c.execute(sqlsent)
results =c.fetchall()
for sen in results:
    print(sen)
```

But as you can see it is quite time consuming from the fact that it needs to iterate through each sentence in my card database to try to find any matching the conditions. My question is there a better way to achieve my results in a much less lengthy way ?

P.S: here is the link to the library used  to tokenize and give dictionary.form() :
https://github.com/WorksApplications/SudachiPy

Comment: Could you please share a test file to upload into sqlite3 for searching?

Comment: @Hermann12 Here is my anki database : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eqcOI3uveGy1IV5oIkC8KjKDngY6ajwr/view?usp=share_link .And Here is the anki database structure https://github.com/ankidroid/Anki-Android/wiki/Database-Structure